# how can I call mutiple functions based on single serial input

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have been working on a project for paralyzed people on Raspberry pi. I wrote a script to get the values out from sensors.

Here I'm using IMU for yaw, pitch and roll values and I got them.

My problem is that I want a python code that can call different functions based on how many time a signal is repeated in a pattern. If the pattern comes up, some given function should be executed.

**till now my code looks like below**

```
import serial
import time
import lcd
import math
import string
lcd.lcd_init()
lcd.stringlcd(0xC0,"welcome")
default_port='/dev/ttyUSB0'
#port = rospy.get_param('device', default_port)
# Check your COM port and baud rate
ser = serial.Serial(port=default_port,baudrate=9600, timeout=1)
##ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600,)#get data fromserial port(IMU)
grad2rad = 3.141592/180.0
roll=0
pitch=0
yaw=0
#rospy.sleep(5) # Sleep for 8 seconds to wait for the board to boot then only write command.
ser.write('#ox' + chr(13)) # To start display angle and sensor reading in text 
while 1:
    line = ser.readline()
    line = line.replace("#YPR=","")
    line = line.replace("#YPRAMG=","")   # Delete "#YPR="
    #f.write(line)                     # Write to the output log file
    words = string.split(line[4:],",")    # Fields split
    #wort5 = float(words[5])                  

    if len(words) > 2:
            try:
                #yaw = float(words[0])*grad2rad
                pitch = -float(words[1])*grad2rad
                roll = -float(words[2])*grad2rad

                if (pitch > 1):
                        lcd.stringlcd(0x80,"right")
                        print ("right")
                elif (pitch < -0.5):
                        lcd.stringlcd(0x80,"left")
                        print ("left")
                if (roll >0.5):
                        lcd.stringlcd(0x80,"forward")
                        print ("forward")
                elif(roll < -0.5):
                        lcd.stringlcd(0x80,"resting")
                        print ("resting")
                time.sleep(1)
                ser.flushInput()
            except Exception as chk:enter code here
                    print chk
```

Comment: Could you give a small example about where you want insert these functions ? or detail where you are stuck exactly ?

Comment: ya sure i need that code continuation of mine.i would like to take the values of pitch and roll,then when roll value hit 1 in a pattern like 2time means it should call one function and 3times means it should call the some other function

Comment: google "state engine". Or in a gross over-simplification, remember how many times things were pushed, and then if you want to call functions, just call them. Here's the first link I found: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

Comment: sorry if said it wrong,but my intention is to call different function based on single input.when i get the input from sensor it should buffer the data for 3 seconds and then read  what pattern is buffered and then call a function that is assigned to that pattern

Comment: @KennyOstrom i appreciate your help,but my bad that i just learned python for this project and  when i googled it (state_machine)it showed me the new terms and i'm new to that topic,can you provide me some help in understanding it or similar example that i can modify to my project would be helpfull

Comment: The simplified version: keep track of how many times it was pushed, so you can call the right function or functions.